# How to pass multi-line data using JSON file

Tags: json, protractor

In my application I need to enter multi-line data in one of the field. Using JSON file how can I pass the data in my protractor script?

Comment: can you share what you've tried so far?

Answer (score 1):

```
var dataFile = require('../../../test-data/queues.json');
```

Inside the spec file you can access the same using dataFile.variableName.

To pass multi-line data you can separate the lines using \n in json file. 
When you pass the data to your application via protractor it will be send as multi-line data.

Please let me know if you need any help regarding json structure.